# SignalR Counting Connections

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, signalr

I am trying to keep track of and count the number of connections connected to my signalR hub, however I am not doing it right.

What I have done is each time a client connects the tally gets incremented , so when I open other tab , I see that it knows there are 2 clients. However I would like the already connected clients to get the updated count which they do not (1st client sees "1") unless I refresh.

C#

```
public Task Connect()
{
    _connections.TryAdd(Context.ConnectionId, null);
    return Clients.tally(_connections.Count.ToString());
}
```

JS

```
chat.tally = function (message) {
    $('#tally').replaceWith(message);
};
```

I have looked at the Wiki but not getting how I implement the callback to all connected clients.

Comment: What you have looks fine. Why are you using .replaceWith() instead of .html()?

Comment: That fixed it , just used .html and now it works well . Thanks very much for taking a look.

Answer (score 0):

Your setup does not not appear to have any major issues, `chat.tally()` should be getting invoked on your connected clients with the correct parameter passed down. Perhaps `message` is not displaying as you intend. Instead of `$('#tally').replaceWith(message);` try `$('#tally').html(message);`